# How to publish web map in ArcIMS

Tags: arcims

I have made a web map with ArcIMS 9.3, and now I want to publish it. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video-tutorial shows the steps to publish the map in ArcIMS:

http://vid01.esri.com/winmmedia/ArcGIS9/ServingArcGISMapsInArcIMS.wmv

Comment: Thank you very much, but i can not play it .

Comment: @GIS Man: Try opening it in Internet Explorer or windows media player.

Comment: OK, thank you very much the problem was due to fire fox browser.thank you again